# How to wait until script ends - csh?

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I execute a script that splits a big file into little files. Immediately afterwards I ask `if (-f *filename) then ....`

Sometimes the script doesn't finish so the `if` doesn't work. I tried `sleep` but that doesn't solve the problem.

My script:
 split -l $number_lines - file2 < file1 >& /dev/null &

How should i use 'wait'?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include your script (or at least the relevant parts) in your question **by updating it** (use `[edit]` below the question

Comment: `wait` doesn't work? I don't know `csh` syntax but you should use a `while (not files) { sleep 1 }` logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to crack your issue wide open.

I am understanding that you are using a C-Shell (I use Bash, but certain environment I interact with use the TCSH.).

#### One method to accomplish your requirement is systemic process-oriented locking.

The Process Locking approach looks most like this:

```
#!/bin/csh
set process_id = $1
set sub_sequent_cmd = $2
set ANTECEDENT_PROC = XXYYZZ
#
while (pidof $ANTECEDENT_PROC)
do
  sleep 10
  if (pidof $ANTECEDENT_PROC)
  then
    sleep .1
  else
    ./sub_sequent_command
    break
  fi
end
```

The premise of the solution is what's important. Monitor the proc with an external script, and when the antecedent proc ends, execute your subsequent script.

**This would only work if you refactor your csh script to be invoked in an exported csh session.**